# Serve different origin as DNS CNAME value, depending on the IP Geolocation

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare, ip-geolocation

I have Next.js Application that is deployed as Lambda Edge and Cloudfront that has S3  static files as origin. AWS Cloudfront URL is the value of example-domain.com CNAME.

Now I have a lot of changes to the Application and I want to deploy those changes.
I don't want these changes to be override current deploy, instead I would like to create new environment and that environment should be available in few countries.

So in this case I would have 2 different Cloudfront URLS:

- oldfeatures.cloudfront.net
- newfeatures.cloudfront.net

Different origin url should be served depending on the geoloaction.

I am not sure that this is the right approach, but I am open for suggestions.

I am managing the domain settings in Cloudflare, all the rest is AWS environment.

How can I achieve this, without making changes to the Applications code.

Comment: Do you have the cloudflare proxy enabled for your domains?

Comment: Are you doing some kind of canary release or A/B testing? Or you actually have separate versions per county (group)?

Comment: I would like to have separate versions. The old version will stay to the rest of the world, the new version should be available for a list of countries

Comment: You should then probably do that properly in the code, as maintaining separate versions will become very messy very soon...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (and cost-effective) option would be to create a Cloudflare (CF) Worker and attach it to your subdomains. Probably better to attach it to both subdomains to ensure they can't access the `newfeatures.cloudfront.net` URL manually if they are 'not allowed' to. The second option would be to use [CF Traffic Steering](https://developers.cloudflare.com/load-balancing/understand-basics/traffic-steering) that comes with the CF Load Balancers feature. This option comes at a small cost and might not really fit your use case - it redirects based on regions rather than countries - I believe you'd need to fork more money and get an enterprise account for country based steering.

That said, the following option using a [CF Worker JavaScript](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/country-code-redirect), will require you to have CF Proxy (the orange cloud) turned on.

Here are 3 options to satisfy your requirements - Recommending option 1 based on my understanding of your question.

```js
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})


async function handleRequest(request) {
    return setRedirect(request) //Change to appropriate function 
}


// Option 1
// Return same newfeatures URL for specific countries based on a country list
// Useful if single URL applies for many countries - I guess that's your case
async function setRedirect(request) {
    const country = request.cf.country
    var cSet = new Set(["US", 
                        "ES", 
                        "FR", 
                        "CA", 
                        "CZ"]);

    if (cSet.has(country)) {  
        return Response.redirect('https://newfeatures.cloudfront.net', 302);
    }
    // Else return oldfeatures URL for all other countries
    else {
        return await fetch(request)
    }
}

// Option 2
const countryMap = {
    US: "https://newfeatures1.cloudfront.net", //URL1
    CA: "https://newfeatures2.cloudfront.net", //URL2
    FR: "https://newfeatures3.cloudfront.net"  //URL3
}

// Return different newfeatures URL for specific countries based on a map 
// Useful if more than two URLs
async function mapRedirect(request) {
    const country = request.cf.country
    
    if (country != null && country in countryMap) {
      const url = countryMap[country]
      return Response.redirect(url, 302)
    }
    // Else return old features for all other countries
    else {
      return await fetch(request)
    }
}

// Option 3
// Return single newfeatures URL for a single country.
// Much simpler one if you only have one specific country to redirect.
async function singleRedirect(request) { 
    const country = request.cf.country
    if (country == 'US'){
        return Response.redirect('https://newfeatures.cloudfront.net', 302)
    }
    // Else return oldfeatures URL for all other countries
    else {
        return await fetch(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: Should all the DNS records stay the same ?
For example:
Type: CNAME
Name: example-domain.com
Content: oldfeatures.cloudfront.net

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question correctly - how would it look like for old and new feature domain?